# tf.data.Dataset: Split and Turn String into Array of Integers

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm using the tf.data.Dataset API and am starting with an `x` numpy array and a `y` numpy array for my labels.  My `x` just consists of strings:

`array([["good movie"], ["terrible film"]]`

So I split into train and test and create a `tf.data.Dataset`:

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.1, random_state=42)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(({"reviews": x_train}, y_train))
```

But now, I'd like to do this:

```
dataset["reviews"] = tf.string_split(dataset["sequence"])
```

But this syntax is incorrect.  I've seen `map` but I don't want to do it to all the columns in my `tf.data.Dataset`.

Also, what is the best way to turn strings into arrays of integers (each word gets a unique integer).  So:

`["good movie"]` might turn into `[2, 4]`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can find a good example about `tf.data` in Tensorflow repository [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/nmt/blob/master/nmt/utils/iterator_utils.py).

In the repository, in addition to its parallel dataset, it includes two dictionary files, named `src_vocab_file` and `trg_vocab_file` which contained all the vocabulary in our corpus.

**First**, it converts these two files into `src_vocab_table` and `trg_vocab_table` with [vocab_utils.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/nmt/blob/master/nmt/utils/vocab_utils.py):

```
from tensorflow.python.ops import lookup_ops

src_vocab_table = lookup_ops.index_table_from_file(
      src_vocab_file, default_value=UNK_ID)
```

**Second**, it split, shorten, and convert the string words in the dataset into IDs with [`iterator_utils.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/nmt/blob/master/nmt/utils/iterator_utils.py):

```
src_dataset = src_dataset.map(lambda src: tf.string_split([src]).values)
src_dataset = src_dataset.map(lambda src: src[:src_max_len])
src_dataset = src_dataset.map(lambda src: tf.cast(src_vocab_table.lookup(src), tf.int32))
```